# How to do custom JSON Marshalling with extra parameters in grails?

Tags: json, grails, marshalling

Until now, I had the Marshallers of my Domain classes defined and registered in Bootstrap. For example I have in my Bootstrap the following marshaller:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Level){Level it->
    return ['name':it.name.encodeAsHTML(),
           'message':it.message?it.message.encodeAsHTML():"",
            'image':it.onImage,
            'minPoints':it.minPoints
    ]
}
```

Now I have to i18n my domain classes, so I'll end up with a Domain class with fields: name_es, name_en... (That's one approach, we are thinking of another, but doesn't affect this question).
Having now different field for each language, when I receive by params the language I want to return the marshalled object but only in the language that was requested. For example if I receive lang='en' I would want to return the marshalled object just with name_en.

How can I achieve this without having to make the explicit return in every method I use?

Comment: Why would you store the same data in different languages in the database?

Comment: Just imagine that you can define a Level in this case in different languages and you will have to show those levels later in the language of the user, just in one of those. For example, 'novato' in spanish or 'newbie' in english